iText 8.0.4 PDFStamper form fills radio buttons revert to circle from any other style (square, diamond, etc.)
We have a library of PDF forms which we're filling with variable content in text, check box and radio button form fields. Since the form is a template, we use the PDFStamper to perform the form fills. Everything is filling and checking appropriately. The problem we have is that the Radio Button controls are set up (in the form) to display a check mark and not the conventional dot within a circle. When filling the form manually with Acrobat reader, the buttons appear as check boxes however; after filling with iText PDFStamper, the resulting PDF radio buttons revert to their conventional style (dot within a circle).
Is this a bug or is it the intended functionality? Is there a work around. We are currently on V8.0.4.
Thanks for any help.
I would like radio buttons to maintain their checktype style after using the PDFStamper.
